What issues commonly afflict 70+ year old bathrooms that warrant major renovations?
I'm a new homeowner and am seeking advice from people who have renovated 70+ year old bathrooms. In short, I'd like to learn what I should look out for in my bathroom that would signal the need for a major renovation.
My husband and I just bought our first home which was built in 1949. We need to make some repairs to the bathroom and want to keep renovations as minimal as possible. However, I'm wondering if there are less apparent problems (at least for newbies) that we should watch out for in a bathroom of this age.
For example, looking at my town's current code for waterproofing, I'm worried there could be mold or water damage under the existing tile or around the floor near the bathtub. If that is the case, that would warrant a much more major fix. As shown in the images, there's exposed drywall and holes in the tile where a shower door was removed. There's also no exhaust fan, just a window for ventilation.
Is there a minimally destructive way to find out, or is this something we would only know if we removed the wall and floor tiles (nothing regarding mold or water damage directly in the bathroom was reported in the general home inspection)?
We've had plumbers inspect the pipes and know about other age-related repairs that need to be made. What I'm more worried about is mold or other unknown unknowns. Appreciate any advice!




Location can be an issue - my parents have a bathroom where the pipes are old ie old in imperial dimensions and this makes repairs and changes slightly more challenging - have to remember to get adaptor fittings etc. Changed the bath, sink and toilet so it's all possible.

The only way you can find out non-destructively is to cut sections of drywall on the walls that are common to other rooms in the house, ( i.e. the linen closet behind the bathtub faucet) in the areas you suspect and check for signs of water leakage or seepage.

One of the things I found in a 1956 bathroom, when I went to replace the vanity, is that the plywood underlayment had delaminated over the years, probably due to water.  I thought I was pulling up shake shingles,  I had to replace much of the floor & re-tile.

Welcome. Your question is rather broad and open-ended. That's not a good fit here. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Also note that Reddit isn't an image host. I can't see your photos.

You should certainly address the damaged areas from the shower door removal (caulk the holes, patch the tile) and you can use a borescope camera to examine the inside of walls through small holes if you have additional concerns you want to check on. You can either use the window or add a fan, ventilation-wise.

As mentioned before, this question is not a good fit here.  You can only answer one question at a time,.  You cant ask for a discussion.

An inspection didn't raise any red flags, why worry about what isn't there.
If an issue is present it will manifest itself with signs like stains or discoloration, soft spots on walls or in floors, paint that is pealing or bubbling or sagging. Mold will make dark marks. If mold is behind tile it will make the lighter grout dark and you will not be able to clean it off. (Remember mold is not radioactive. You won't die because you entered a room where there may be some.)
Holes in walls in the shower certainly need to be filled, but if the wall is not soft, don't assume there is an issue.
This falls under my fathers belief; "If it isn't broke, don't fix it."

And his other belief: F--- around and find out...
